# Calling Static Member Function causes runtime error

Tags: c++

I am getting a runtime access violation error when defining a static class variable. I'm not quite sure what is exactly going wrong; is the static function I am calling not implemented at the time of calling, something else?

What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Runtime error (see code below for the line that the error occurs on):

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Code:

```
// Status.h
class Status
{
public:
    // Static Properties//
    static const Status CS_SUCCESS;

    // Static Functions //
    static const Status registerState(const tstring &stateMsg)
    {
        int nextStateTmp = nextState + 1;
        auto res = states.emplace(std::make_pair(nextStateTmp, stateMsg));

        return (res.second) ? Status(++nextState) : Status(res.first->first);
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;
    static STATE nextState;
};


// Status.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Status.h"

// Class Property Implementation //
State Status::nextState = 50000;
std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> Status::states;
const Status S_SUCCESS = Status::registerState(_T("Success"));


// IApp.h
class IApp : protected Component
{
public:

    static const Status S_APP_EXIT;
    static const Status S_UNREGISTERED_EVT;

    ...
};


// IApp.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../EventDelegate.h"
#include "../Component.h"
#include "IApp.h"

// Class Property Implementation //
const Status IApp::S_APP_EXIT = CStatus::registerState(_T("IApp exit")); // Runtime error: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
const Status IApp::S_UNREGISTERED_EVT = CStatus::registerState(_T("No components registered for this event"));
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Have you used a debugger to debug your application, and if not, why not?  2) Instead of posting various random parts of your code that cannot be compiled on their own, you need to post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information. I see nothing in your question that's specific to the Microsoft Windows Platform, so your Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example must be compilable and executable on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Some static variables like `S_APP_EXIT` depend on other static variables (e.g. `nextState`) for their initialization.

Read about the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) and fix your code accordingly (making `nextState` a private variable?). You might even think of using the *Construct On First Use Idiom* (explained in the other FAQ [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use)).

Anyway I wouldn't generally advise keeping all those variables static, but it's quite hard to tell from just the excerpt you posted (where is `CS_SUCCESS` defined?).